# Using Unique Indices versus Querying the Database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I am working on a login / registration system in *node.js*.

I *usually* query the database, to check whether the given username already exists, and if it doesn't, I create the new user.

I got the idea recently, of using the Unique Index in the MySQL database for the username. I have some questions though.

- *What would be the most efficient way to check for duplicates? Search the database for the given username, or use the Unique Index and catch an error from MySQL if it already exists?*

I feel unsafe with MySQL spitting out errors when duplicates are made, but maybe I'm just crazy.

- *If I were to use the Unique Index, would it still be efficient to use it for every unique value? Such as having a Unique index for the username, email etc.?*

Comment: You should be using unique key. unique keys aren't prone to race conditions. Qeurying a SELECT duplicate check is prone to a race condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be the most efficient way to check for duplicates? Search the database for the given username, or use the Unique Index and catch an error from MySQL if it already exists?

In first case you will be finding the user with username and then check whether it is found or not. So in this case your DB checks for this username and you also put one check.

Now consider second case where unique index is present. So you give mysql the data and it will try to check first and either throws the error or put the data into DB. This way you don't have to check double if the usrname is already in the DB or not. This will also save you from race conditions

If you are worrying about the mysql throwing errors then don't worry. mysql will throw an integrity error which you can catch and send appropriate response like username exists already

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you very much! I wasn't aware of the race conditions problem, so it's definitely good to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use Unique Indexes (with the validation occurring in the database engine), because this avoids thread races and ensures database integrity. Validating through select is unsafe and not a recommended way of doing it.

With that said, I recommend checking with a select before inserting to notify the user of the "username taken" before the tentative to insert.

Another good reason to use Unique Indexes is the performance. Depending on the size of the table, it can be way faster.

Comment: By: "I recommend checking with a select before inserting" do you refer to querying the database?

Comment: Yes. This avoids exceptions being raised in the app.

Comment: But the main reason I want to use Unique Indices is to avoid querying the database?